# Object recognition for road design features

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr

I am looking to do pattern recognition on traffic design layouts to assist signal and traffic experts who do audits.

Essentially this would involve pulling text from a pdf / image and verifying it, while also looking for certain objects on a layout (almost always have the same dimensions) and making sure they are the right distance away from things like kerbs.

Here's an example image

The benefit would be large as a lot of traffic consultancies do a lot of work auditing these so this would automate that.

I've been looking at using Azure's computer vision library and using the online version have gotten the text pulled from parts of the image.

I am comfortable using Python and openCV and happy to look into any ML libraries needed. Ideally want a fast solution and not to rebuild the wheel so to speak.

The end result would be removing around 50% of audit work.

Comment: That sounds pretty cool. Do you have a question or need help though? You should look through the site rules to make sure your question can even be asked while also following the site's rules - typically this site is for solving problems in code that people have posted, not something this general.

Comment: Fair enough - just trying to get to grips with how I would approach this sort of problem

Comment: Any idea where I would post about it?

Comment: that's more something for a PHD thesis, not a problem you discuss in a few lines on stack overflow.